# When multiple devices connect at the same time, my app crashes with an error

Tags: rxandroidble

When multiple devices connect at the same time, my app crashes with the below error. Why is this, and how can I resolve it?

When I force devices to connect sequentially after scanning, it works nicely.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
        at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
    Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException
        at rx.Observable$27.onError(Observable.java:7923)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
        at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:147)
        at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$ReplayProducer.replay(CachedObservable.java:404)
        at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.dispatch(CachedObservable.java:220)
        at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.onError(CachedObservable.java:201)
        at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState$1.onError(CachedObservable.java:175)
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:225)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
        at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onError(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:227)
        at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:147)
        at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject$UnboundedReplayState.accept(ReplaySubject.java:465)
        at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject$UnboundedReplayState.replayObserverFromIndex(ReplaySubject.java:514)
        at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject$UnboundedReplayState.replayObserver(ReplaySubject.java:502)
        at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject.caughtUp(ReplaySubject.java:427)
        at rx.subjects.ReplaySubject.onError(ReplaySubject.java:387)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.RxBleRadioOperation.onError(RxBleRadioOperation.java:84)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.RxBleRadioOperation$1.onError(RxBleRadioOperation.java:50)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onError(OperatorSingle.java:139)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onError(OperatorTake.java:62)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:240)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:776)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:537)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:526)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:810)
        at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:147)
        at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.accept(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:318)
        at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitLoop(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:291)
        at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitFirst(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:270)
        at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject$1.call(BehaviorSubject.java:106)
        at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject$1.call(BehaviorSubject.java:102)
        at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.add(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:95)
        at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:60)
        at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:35)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:232)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:142)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.fastpath(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:127)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:70)
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:49)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:32)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8191)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8158)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.operations.RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover.lambda$run$71(RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover.java:34)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.operations.RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover.access$lambda$0(RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover.java)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.operations.RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8191)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8158)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.operations.RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover.run(RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover.java:44)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.radio.RxBleRadioImpl$$Lambda$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at rx.Observable$27.onNext(Observable.java:7928)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:139)
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$ScalarSynchronousAction.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:115)
        at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: BleGattException{status=22, bleGattOperation=BleGattOperation{description='CONNECTION_STATE'}}
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.connection.RxBleGattCallback.propagateStatusErrorIfGattErrorOccurred(RxBleGattCallback.java:245)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.connection.RxBleGattCallback.access$100(RxBleGattCallback.java:26)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.connection.RxBleGattCallback$1.onConnectionStateChange(RxBleGattCallback.java:62)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:181)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:70)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

------- Code Class --

```
package com.ths.bts.bt;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;

import com.polidea.rxandroidble.RxBleConnection;
import com.polidea.rxandroidble.RxBleDevice;
import com.polidea.rxandroidble.RxBleDeviceServices;
import com.ths.bts.utils.Defs;
import com.ths.bts.utils.Utility;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;


public class RXClass {

    private String macAddress;
    private RxBleDevice rxBleDevice;
    private RxBleConnection connection;
    private rx.Observable<RxBleConnection> connectionObservable;
    private Subscription subscription;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private BleProfileManager bleProfileManager;
    private Handler mActionHandler = null;
    private PublishSubject<Void> disconnectTriggerSubject = null;
    private HashMap<UUID,BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charMap = new HashMap<>();
    public BleProfileManager getBleProfileManager() {
        return bleProfileManager;
    }

    public PublishSubject<Void> getDisconnectTriggerSubject() {
        return disconnectTriggerSubject;
    }

    public void setDisconnectTriggerSubject(PublishSubject<Void> disconnectTriggerSubject) {
        this.disconnectTriggerSubject = disconnectTriggerSubject;
    }

    public void setBleProfileManager(BleProfileManager bleProfileManager) {
        this.bleProfileManager = bleProfileManager;
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public Subscription getSubscription() {
        return subscription;
    }

    public void setSubscription(Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
    }

    public Observable<RxBleConnection> getConnectionObservable() {
        return connectionObservable;
    }

    public void setConnectionObservable(Observable<RxBleConnection> connectionObservable) {
        this.connectionObservable = connectionObservable;
    }

    public String getMacAddress() {
        return macAddress;
    }

    public void setMacAddress(String macAddress) {
        this.macAddress = macAddress;
    }

    public RxBleDevice getRxBleDevice() {
        return rxBleDevice;
    }

    public void setRxBleDevice(RxBleDevice rxBleDevice) {
        this.rxBleDevice = rxBleDevice;
    }

    public RxBleConnection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void setConnection(RxBleConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public RXClass(String address)
    {
        this.macAddress = address;
        mActionHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }




    public byte[] getSecurityCommand(String address)
    {
        String second = address.substring(3, 5);
        String fifth = address.substring(12, 14);
        String command = fifth.trim() + "3663" + second.trim();
        byte b[] = hexStringToByteArray(command);

        return b;
    }

    public synchronized byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[(len / 2)];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void readAllChars(List<BluetoothGattService> services)
    {
        for (BluetoothGattService service : services)
        {
            if(service.getCharacteristics().size() > 0 && !service.getCharacteristics().get(0).getUuid().equals(Defs.CHAR_ALERT_LEVEL_UUID)
                    && !service.getCharacteristics().get(0).getUuid().equals(Defs.CHAR_CUSTOM_SERVICE_UUID))
            {
                int props = service.getCharacteristics().get(0).getProperties();
                if ((props & 2) != 0) {
                    charMap.put(service.getCharacteristics().get(0).getUuid(), service.getCharacteristics().get(0));
                    readCharacterisitc(service.getCharacteristics().get(0).getUuid());
                }



            }

        }
    }

    public void connect()
    {

    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        if(subscription != null) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();

            Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Disconnecting  - " + this.device.getAddress() + " - " + rxBleDevice.getConnectionState());
            if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
            {
                mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                            Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("eventType", "ondisconnect");
                            Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_DEVICE_DISCONNECT);
                            bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                            msg.setData(bundle);
                            msg.sendToTarget();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }





    }


    public int getConnectionState()
    {
        if(this.rxBleDevice != null)
        {
            if(rxBleDevice.getConnectionState() == RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.CONNECTED)
                return bleProfileManager.STATE_PROFILE_CONNECTED;
            if(rxBleDevice.getConnectionState() == RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)
                return bleProfileManager.STATE_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED;
            if(rxBleDevice.getConnectionState() == RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.CONNECTING)
                return bleProfileManager.STATE_PROFILE_STATE_CONNECTING;
            if(rxBleDevice.getConnectionState() == RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.DISCONNECTING)
                return bleProfileManager.STATE_PROFILE_STATE_DISCONNECTING;
        }
        return bleProfileManager.STATE_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED;
    }

    public void unscribe()
    {
        if(subscription != null && subscription.isUnsubscribed())
            subscription.unsubscribe();


    }

    private void triggerDisconnect() {
        disconnectTriggerSubject.onNext(null);
    }


    public void readRemoteRssi() {
        connection.readRssi()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onRSSIReadSuccess, this::onRSSIReadFailure);
    }

    public void readCharacterisitc(UUID iCharUuid)
    {
        connection.readCharacteristic(iCharUuid)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onReadSuccess, this::onReadFailure);
    }

    public void writeCharacteristic(UUID iCharUuid,
                                    byte[] data)
    {
        connection.writeCharacteristic(iCharUuid, data)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onWriteSuccess, this::onWriteFailure);
    }

    public void writeCharacteristic(UUID iCharUuid,
                                    int data)
    {
        byte b[] = new byte[1];
        b[0]  = (byte)data;
        connection.writeCharacteristic(iCharUuid, b)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onWriteSuccess, this::onWriteFailure);
    }

    public void enableNotification(UUID iCharUuid)
    {
        connection.setupNotification(iCharUuid)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable)
                .subscribe(this::onNotificationReceived, this::onNotificationSetupFailure);

    }

    public BluetoothGattCharacteristic getCharacteristic(UUID iCharUuid)
    {
        return charMap.get(iCharUuid);
    }




    // Call backs

    public void onConnectionFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Connection Failed" + this.macAddress);

        if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
        {
            mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                        Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("eventType", "ondisconnect");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_DEVICE_CONNECTION_FAILED);
                        bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        msg.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    public void onConnectionReceived(RxBleConnection connection) {
        Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Connection Success - " + this.macAddress);
        this.connection = connection;
        connection.discoverServices().subscribe(this::onServiceDiscovered);
        if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
        {
            mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                        Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("eventType", "onConnectionStateChange");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_DEVICE_CONNECT);
                        bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        msg.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            });

        }



    }


    public void onConnectionStateChange(RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState newState) {
        //Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Connection Status - " + newState);

    }

    public void onServiceDiscovered(RxBleDeviceServices services) {
        Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Services Success - " + this.macAddress);
        writeCharacteristic(Defs.CHAR_CUSTOM_CONNECTION_UUID, getSecurityCommand(this.macAddress));
        if(services != null)
        {
            readAllChars(services.getBluetoothGattServices());
        }


        if(charMap.get(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_NOTIFY_UUID) != null)
            readCharacterisitc(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_NOTIFY_UUID);

        if(charMap.get(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_NOTIFY_UUID) != null)
            readCharacterisitc(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_NOTIFY_UUID);

        if(charMap.get(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_CONNECTION_UUID) != null)
            writeCharacteristic(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_CONNECTION_UUID, getSecurityCommand(this.macAddress));

        if(charMap.get(Defs.CHAR_CUSTOM_CONNECTION_UUID) != null)
            writeCharacteristic(Defs.CHAR_CUSTOM_CONNECTION_UUID, getSecurityCommand(this.macAddress));

        if(charMap.get(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_NOTIFY_UUID) != null)
            enableNotification(Defs.CHAR_BIOSENSOR_NOTIFY_UUID);

        if(charMap.get(Defs.CHAR_AUTOMATION_IO) != null)
            enableNotification(Defs.CHAR_AUTOMATION_IO);

        try{ConnectionManager.resetWait(device.getAddress());}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
        {
            mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                        Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("eventType", "onServicesDiscovered");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_SERVICE_DISCOVERY_DONE);
                        bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        msg.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void onReadFailure(Throwable throwable) {

    }

    public void onReadSuccess(byte[] b) {
        if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
        {
            mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                        Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("eventType", "oncharread");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_GATT_ON_CHAR_READ);
                        bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        msg.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void onWriteSuccess(byte[] b) {
        if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
        {
            mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                        Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("eventType", "oncharwrite");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_GATT_ON_CHAR_WRITE);
                        bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        msg.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }


    public void onNotificationReceived(byte[] bytes) {
        Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Noification Recevied" + this.macAddress);
        if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
        {

            mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                        Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("eventType", "oncharwrite");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_DEVICE_CLIP_UPDATE);
                        bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        msg.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void notificationHasBeenSetUp() {

    }

    public void onNotificationSetupFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Noification Failed" + this.macAddress);

    }

    public void onRSSIReadSuccess(int rssi) {
        Defs.B_DEVICES_RSSI_MAP.put(this.macAddress, new Integer(rssi));
        if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
        {

            mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                        Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("eventType", "oncharwrite");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_DEVICE_READ_SSI);
                        bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        msg.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }
    public void onRSSIReadFailure(Throwable throwable) {

    }


    public void onWriteFailure(Throwable throwable) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have skimmed through the code and I have found a `connection.discoverServices().subscribe(this::onServiceDiscovered);` without error handling in:

```
public void onConnectionReceived(RxBleConnection connection) {
    Utility.infoLog("NANI", "Connection Success - " + this.macAddress);
    this.connection = connection;
    connection.discoverServices().subscribe(this::onServiceDiscovered);
    if(bleProfileManager != null && bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers() != null )
    {
        mActionHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().size(); i++) {
                    Handler handler = bleProfileManager.getRemoteHandlers().get(i);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("eventType", "onConnectionStateChange");
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, Defs.HDLR_MSG_DEVICE_CONNECT);
                    bundle.putParcelable(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Additionally you have a mistake in:

```
public void unscribe()
{
    if(subscription != null && subscription.isUnsubscribed())
        subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

It should be `if(subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed())` because otherwise it will never unsubscribe.

Comment: Aah thanks a lot, yes it got slipped, i am trying now it self

Comment: Thank you very much, its working nicely, no error in 5 runs, thanks a lot